# Informix SQL Execute Function Inside FOREACH Cursor

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, cursor, informix

Informix versions 11.70 - 12.10

Trying to create a Stored Procedure to get the Session ID of the user that has locked a table, and then Execute a built-in Function using that Session ID. I don't write too many procedures in Informix.

Getting a syntax error around WITH RESUME.

Any help?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_kill_lock ()

RETURNING
  INT as User_Session
;

-- declaration of variables
DEFINE rsUser_Session INT;

-- SELECT each User Session that has a lock on a table
SELECT DISTINCT s.sid AS User_Session
FROM sysmaster:syslocks l, sysmaster:syssessions s 
WHERE s.sid = l.owner 
   AND dbsname <> 'sysmaster' 
ORDER BY 1 
INTO TEMP tempSession;

--Cursor
FOREACH 
   SELECT User_Session
   INTO rsUser_Session
   FROM tempSession

RETURN
rsUser_Session;

--kill the session returned
EXECUTE FUNCTION sysadmin:task("onmode","z",rsUser_Session)

WITH RESUME
;

END FOREACH
END PROCEDURE;


 -- Permissions for routine "sp_kill_lock"
 grant execute on function sp_kill_lock to 'public';
```

I changed the code, and at least I'm not getting a syntax error anymore. Now it says the function is returning too many values:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_kill_lock ()

RETURNING
  INT as User_Session
;

-- declaration of variables
DEFINE rsUser_Session INT;

-- SELECT each User Session that has a lock on a table
SELECT DISTINCT s.sid AS User_Session
FROM sysmaster:syslocks l, sysmaster:syssessions s 
WHERE s.sid = l.owner 
   AND dbsname <> 'sysmaster' 
ORDER BY 1 
INTO TEMP tempSession;

--Cursor
FOREACH 
   SELECT User_Session
   INTO rsUser_Session
   FROM tempSession

--removed this RETURN
--RETURN
--rsUser_Session;

--kill the session returned
EXECUTE FUNCTION sysadmin:admin("onmode","z",rsUser_Session);

--removed the WITH RESUME

END FOREACH
END PROCEDURE;
```

For testing a locked table:

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE mytable IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WITH RESUME` is part of the `RETURN` statement, so in your first example it should be:

```
RETURN rsUser_Session WITH RESUME;
```

But it will still give you an error when executed because `PROCEDURE`cannot return values. You need to change to it to `CREATE FUNCTION`.

Then it probably does not do what you want, because it is returning before it executes the `onmode -z`, so, for example, if there is only 1 session to kill, it will never execute the `onmode -z` . Plus it is leaving a temp table behind.

So lets rewrite it, to always execute the `onmode -z` and not use a temp table (I am using Informix 12.10.FC10DE):

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_kill_lock ()
RETURNING
    INT AS user_session
    , INT AS admin_result
;
-- declaration of variables
DEFINE rsuser_session INT;
DEFINE rsadmin_result INT;

-- SELECT each User Session that has a lock on a table
FOREACH 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        s.sid AS user_session
    INTO
        rsuser_session
    FROM 
        sysmaster:syslocks AS l
        INNER JOIN 
        sysmaster:syssessions AS s 
        ON
            s.sid = l.owner
    WHERE  
        dbsname <> 'sysmaster' 
    ORDER BY 1 

   LET rsadmin_result = sysadmin:admin('onmode', 'z', rsuser_session);
   -- returning session id and admin execute result which is the value of cmd_number in the table sysadmin:command_history
   RETURN rsuser_session, rsadmin_result WITH RESUME;

END FOREACH
END FUNCTION;
```

1. [Informix SPL statements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1301.htm)
2. [Informix Relationship Between Routines, Functions, and Procedures](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0458.htm#ids_sqs_0458)

Comment: Wow, thanks Luis! When I "execute function sp_kill_lock()" I am getting an error: SQL Error (-79716): System or internal error. Is that the function killing my own connection because I'm the one locking the table? I really appreciate your help sir!

Comment: Nevermind, I opened a new Server Studio window, locked the table via that window, and executed the function in the original window and got the columns: "user_session" and "admin_result" returned. The new window got the error, so it was just killing my own session. This is awesome work Luis. I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. To correct my previous comment, you can kill your own session if the lock is in any database besides the `sysmaster`. You can add more logic to the `FUNCTION` to avoid killing the session where it is executing.